# httpURLconnection - changed URL having no effect

Tags: android, android-asynctask, server, httpurlconnection

I'm working on an Android app that connects to a remote web server using httpURLconnect and a URL String. for development I used a wamp localhost, which was reflected in the URL String (ip address censored):

`String login_URL = "http://***.***.**.*/AndroidTest1/login.php"`

Once i'd set up an online web server, i changed the connection String to reflect this:

```
'String login_URL = "http://**.***.***.***/home/ubuntu/login.php";
```

The problem is that now when I run the app with it's new URL String, it seems to continue to refer to the old URL (instead of making changes in online database, changes occur in local DB), which I can't make sense of.

Would hugely appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you (re) build/clean/upload the new code to the android device? As last resort, try uninstalling the app from the device and installing the version with the correct url (note that you'll lose app preferences in case you are using any).

Comment: probably instant run thinking you haven't changed anything.

Comment: FirstOne - thanks, a full reinstall of the app seems to have done the trick! Also sorry for the unnecessary tag, it was recommended by stackOverflow so I just went with it - will be more careful in future.